# Amazon AWS - Amazon Connect IAM policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was trying to lock down user account just to Amazon Connect, Lambda and S3. I was able to give permissions to S3 and Lambda but I cannot find permissions for Amazon Connect. I have went through the documentation etc. but I cannot find out the proper name of that service so I will be able to write a policy for it. Would you be able to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a generator for policies in IAM (Into IAM -> Policies -> Create), choosing connect gives me the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "connect:DescribeInstance",
                "connect:CreateInstance",
                "connect:ModifyInstance",
                "connect:ListInstances",
                "connect:GetFederationTokens",
                "connect:DestroyInstance",
                "connect:GetFederationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

There's a warning on the action part saying:

- connect:DescribeInstance action requires 7 more actions to provide full permissions
- connect:CreateInstance action requires 13 more actions to provide full permissions
- connect:ModifyInstance action requires 10 more actions to provide full permissions

Each of them says:

To allow an entity to call 'DescribeInstance', grant all of the following required permissions.

- firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream
- firehose:ListDeliveryStreams
- kinesis:DescribeStream
- kinesis:ListStreams
- kms:DescribeKey
- kms:ListAliases
- s3:ListAllMyBuckets

To allow an entity to call 'CreateInstance', grant all of the following required permissions.

- ds:CreateAlias
- ds:DeleteDirectory
- ds:DescribeDirectories
- firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream
- firehose:ListDeliveryStreams
- kinesis:DescribeStream
- kinesis:ListStreams
- kms:CreateGrant
- kms:DescribeKey
- kms:ListAliases
- kms:RetireGrant
- s3:CreateBucket
- s3:ListAllMyBuckets

To allow an entity to call 'ModifyInstance', grant all of the following required permissions.

- firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream
- firehose:ListDeliveryStreams
- kinesis:DescribeStream
- kinesis:ListStreams
- kms:CreateGrant
- kms:DescribeKey
- kms:ListAliases
- kms:RetireGrant
- s3:CreateBucket
- s3:ListAllMyBuckets

Which once compiled gives the following policy when not filtering on any resource:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "connect:DescribeInstance",
                "connect:ModifyInstance",
                "connect:GetFederationTokens",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kms:RetireGrant",
                "connect:DestroyInstance",
                "firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream",
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "connect:CreateInstance",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "connect:ListInstances",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "ds:DescribeDirectories",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "firehose:ListDeliveryStreams",
                "ds:CreateAlias",
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "connect:GetFederationToken",
                "ds:DeleteDirectory"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know how I have missed this.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer, @mrktos